# Convert PDF to Docx using MS "Add In" Office.js SDK

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

The standard approach for Office automation has been to program against COM interfaces (e.g. Office Primary Interop Assembly), and this only works on a Windows OS.  Instead, I am interested in using the new Office "Add In" technology, which replaces COM with [Office.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#office-javascript-apis) and is cross-platform.

In particular, I want to use this new Office.js automation technology to convert a PDF to Docx.  Is this possible?  Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am interested in using the new Office "Add In" technology, which replaces COM with Office.js and is cross-platform.

You are on the wrong avenue. The Office JavaScript API is not a replacement for the COM technology. I bet COM will exist with us and nothing will replace it in near future. I'd say Office JS API is an alternative way of developing add-ins for MS Office applications where you could support multiple supports. But the API is under active development at this time which means there is no feature parity between them atm.

> In particular, I want to use this new Office.js automation technology to convert a PDF to Docx. Is this possible? Does anyone have an example?

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that. Office add-in work under the context of currently opened document only. The best what you could do is to get a string (`base64`) which represents the document and pass it to any web service (backend side) for converting.

Answer (score 0):

Office Add-Ins are just basically websites that can talk to the Office API. If you can design  a website to convert PDF to Docx then an Add-In can do it likely. But, be aware you will be constrained by the security inherent to browser sandboxes.

You can run a backend server that does this processing such as NodeJS and have the Add-In call/recieve the information as desired or try and process client side in the browser.

Here is something I found w/ a quick google --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-convert-docx?activeTab=readme

Comment: My cursory read of the documentation made reference to two different browser contexts.  One is "in a sandbox" (ergo, not running on a remote server) and the other...on a remote server.  Kinda confusing...but if indeed they have a browser sandbox, then presumably(?) I could use the Office.js tooling to perform some amount of automation.

Comment: @BrentArias I'm wondering if your missing the basic concept. My thinking would be `browser context` refers to the browser on the users terminal. The `remote server` would be the WebServer hosting the HTML/JS Files. You can also do a LOT more on the backend which you'll need to get it working anyway.